How to display a dotted musical note with Vexflow?
How to display a dotted note with vexflow. For example dans le code suivant : new Vex.Flow.StaveNote({keys: ["c/4"], duration: "qd" }  the "d" is taken into account in the duration of the note but is not displayed in the scope
Version vexFlow : 4.2.2
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vexflow@4.2.2/build/cjs/vexflow.js">
